# get all LI within UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find all `li` within `ul`

if I do

```
console.log(element);
```

I get the ul element output in firebug.

If I `console.log(element[0]);` I get undefined.

Now to try to find all `li` within `ul` I do:

```
 $('li', element).each(function (index) {
            console.log(index);
});
```

But my index never gets outputed.

If I do:

```
$('li', element[0]).each(function (index) {
            console.log(index);
            $(this).data('previousIndex', index);
        });
```

I get too many index count outputed to my console. My ul only has 3-4 `li` but I get some false count outputed.

Can anybody tell me my mistake?

**EDIT:**

To give more idea I am using sortable plugin. This is my firebug output when I do a `children()`. I am not sure why is this happening.

[image]

Comment: How do you define and initialize `element`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `element` is still the DOM element `<ul>` and not a jQuery object. Because if it were, `element[0]` should *not* be undefined.

So to operate jQuery on the `element`, wrap it in jQuery first then use `children('li')` to get immediate children `<li>` or `find('li')` to get all descendant (nested) `<li>`

```
//find all children li
$(element).children('li');

//find all descendant li (all nested li)
$(element).find('li');
```

Comment: +1, it's what happens most probably. Especially the second symptom: If `element` is the DOM node and `element[0]` is hence undefined, then `$('li', undefined)` will get _all_ `li`s in the document.

Comment: @Joseph: I have posted the output of what I get when I do    *console.log($(element).children());* Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Since `li` are the only valid children of `ul`, you can just get the `ul`'s `children` property (or `.children()` method call in jQuery).